# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - ERROR: No Application Version named 'v0_9_2-76-gf5a4' found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my code to AWS Beanstalk and get this error.  I researched that it could be that the number of versions is more than 500, so I deleted a lot of versions.  But, I still get this error.

```
eb deploy
ERROR: No Application Version named 'v0_9_2-76-gf5a4' found.
```

I also tried

```
git aws.push
Error: Failed to create the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application version
```

Edit:
Trying with `eb deploy --debug` I now get:

> Instance: i-2ad238d5 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed . Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed with returncode 18
>
> ebcli.objects.exceptions.ServiceError: Update environment operation is
> complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting
> documentation.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `eb deploy --debug`?

Comment: eb deploy
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed with returncode 18
ERROR: [Instance: i-2ad238d5 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed

Comment: vipul$ eb deploy --debug
2015-05-11 11:06:27,291 (DEBUG) eb : logging initialized for 'eb' using LoggingLogHandler
2015-05-11 11:06:27,291 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /etc/eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2015-05-11 11:06:27,292 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /Users/vipul/.eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2015-05-11 11:06:27,294 (DEBUG) eb : collecting arguments/commands for <ebcli.core.base.EbBaseController object at 0x10e633950>
2015-05-11 11:06:27,298 (DEBUG) eb : collecting arguments/commands

Comment: You'll have to add it as an edit to your question or put in pastebin or something because a comment is not sufficient for all the debug log.

Comment: I just updated the question.  Instance: i-2ad238d5 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .

Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed with returncode 18

INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

Comment: This error usually happens because of dependencies or .ebextensions. Are you using .ebextensions?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk used to have issues with package names. I remember having issues with "-" in the names. I don't deploy manually anymore. You can try by removing dashes?

Answer (score 18):

Did you update the file `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` ? It may have a wrong setup.

1. Make a backup of `.elasticbeanstalk/` folder and remove it
2. Execute `eb create`
3. Select the same region you deployed it before. You can check the region on `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` backup
4. A list with the environments will appear, select the right one
5. Deploy now
6. Remove the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` backup

Comment: I had a different region and application name. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I had to run eb -init to add SSH support, and the application_name in config.yml changed.

Comment: For step 2 it should rather be "eb init", this command creates a new config.yml file

Comment: @albert if it wasn't against stackoverflow rules I would make aa million temp accounts and up vote this aggressively. thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Check for the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file

```
environment: CORRECT_ENV_NAME
   global:
     application_name: CORRECT_APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was doing `eb deploy X` where X was an environment for a different project.

Answer (score 1):

When I had the error

> InvalidParameterValueError: No Application Version named 'app-9f5c-180927_071528' found.

I fixed this by specifying the label I wanted to push up.

> eb deploy XXX-env -l XXX.0.0.1

The -l flag is documented [AWS EB Deploy Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html)

Comment: Good call. Easy mistake to make. --version for an existing version, --label to create a version from that label.

Answer (score 0):

most likely, the deploy is trying an incorrect Elasticbeanstalk Application. it could be because you renamed the application in the AWS console.

so double check you're pointing to the correct elasticbeanstalk Environment and Application. it could be picking out default values from your .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file.